# vim - how to include next/n in a map?

Tags: vim

I'm running gvim 7.4 on windows and trying to append 'n' to a map and it works, except when it reaches the next search value it goes into insert mode, forcing me to hit escape. E.g., if I start a search for 'hi' and then create a map `:map g cwHello<C-O>n`, when I hit 'g', it replaces 'hi' with 'Hello', escapes, search forwards to the next 'hi', and then goes into insert mode? This is really slowing me down.

As an aside, I'm used to vi's ^[ for escape but gvim doesn't seem to accept that.

Comment: How do you pasted `^[` into macro? Did you use `Ctrl+v Esc` combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `<C-O>` with `<Esc>`. `<C-O>` only treats the next key as normal-mode, it doesn't exit from insert mode. Thus, your mapping doesn't "go into insert mode" at the end; you never leave it.